# Flying along route Cesium JS

Tags: cesiumjs

I just started experimenting with Cesium JS, loaded my data in WMS and WFS from Geoserver.

What I want to do now is how can I create an animation to fly along the tracking route ??

[image: picture01]

I want to achieve the same result as [veloviewer](https://blog.veloviewer.com/fly-through-your-strava-activities-routes-and-segments-with-cesium-earth-view/) more or less.

I've searched through forums but what I found is mostly about how to fly to a certain location.

Regards,

Yogi

Comment: Typically one uses a `Cesium.SampledPositionProperty` to make the vehicle move, and then the camera tracks the vehicle.  For example, see: https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Interpolation.html

Comment: okay, thank you :)